# How do you get rid of very strong stale odors coming out of a sink with garbage disposal?

Tags: kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

We redid our kitchen within the last year and our sink has a garbage disposer and a dishwasher next to the disposer. Recently, we have been smelling very stale odors that we think are coming from the sink drain. We used baking soda/vinegar, lemon rinds, Mr. Clean, filling up sink with soap and although the smell goes away for a while sometimes, it returns every time we turn on the water. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem that is causing the odors to pervade the entire kitchen and hallway? Thanks.

Comment: Is it missing a trap under the garbage disposal?  You do run water down it for a bit after the crunching has stopped?? Is there a plug you can put into the top of the insinkerator when not in use?

Comment: is there a wind blowing out of the sink drain?

Comment: Yes I run water. I can put a plug in the sink but everytime the water goes on, it smells again. There is no wind blowing out of the sink, How can I tell if it is missing a trap???

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include pictures of the piping under the sink.

Answer (score 2):

### That foul smell that just won't go away is almost certainly sewer gas.

It sounds like you either have:

- Something bypassing the trap. Typically someone not familiar with plumbing putting an entrance for a dishwasher drain or the like after the trap, not before it.
- Or a trap is missing.
- Or you have a failed mechanical vent (I hate mechanical vents,
  because they fail) - Also Known As: Studor vents (a brand name) and AAVs (Air Admittance Valves.)
- Or (far less common) a broken vent pipe.

An additional possibility is that you have an inappropriate trap/vent arrangement (S-trap, unvented trap, crown vented trap) that is siphoning itself dry, so it's not a functional trap.

Comment: Actually, the smell did go away after my contractor told me to make sure never to leave unwashed dishes in the dishwasher ovenight. The dishwasher is adjacent to the sink. I just had thought it was something else.